# Second to the LastIndexOf C#

Tags: c#

***  I cannot delete this duplicate question because someone has answered it ***

I have file names formatted  CustomerInfoDaily.12042014.080043 and  CustomerInfoDaily.A.12042014.080043    I'm trying to get the base name (CustomerInfoDaily) and the base suffix (.12042014.080043) using substrings.  There is no limit to the number of periods however the suffix is always .\d{8}.\d{8}

```
string fn = "CustomerInfoDaily.A.12042014.080043";
string baseFileName = fn.Substring(0, fn.LastIndexOf(".",fn.Length-1,fn.Length));
string baseSuffix = fn.Substring(fn.LastIndexOf(".", 0, 2));
```

The problem is that you can say you want the first or last dot but there is no saying that you want the second to the last instance of the dot.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's not quite true. You *can* delete a question even if it has one answer, provided that answer has no upvotes and is not accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using `string.Split`:

```
string fn = "CustomerInfoDaily.A.12042014.080043";

var split = fn.Split('.');
var last = split.LastOrDefault();
var secondLast = split.Skip(split.Length - 2).FirstOrDefault();
```